# Using angularjs $scope in the get url params collection?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, parameters

AngularJS newb here, working on my first app (with .NET on the server). I want to call the WebAPI and pass it two parameters stored in $scope, but it won't do it. If I hard code the values it works fine, but not if I use $scope.

This works:

```
$http.get("/api/v1/entries", { params: { workgroupId:"3", reportedOn: "5/23/1968" } })
```

This does not work and actually causes AngularJS to stop functioning it altogether:

```
$http.get("/api/v1/entries", {params: {workgroupId:$scope.params.workgroupId, reportedOn:$scope.params.reportedOn}})
```

This does not work either:

```
  $http.get("/api/v1/entries?workgroupId=" + $scope.params.workgroupId + "&reportedOn=" + $scope.params.reportedOn)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please provide the console error? Also, is this code inside your controller? In fact, if you can provide the relevant code from your controller as well, that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried your code and it worked for me, so you must not have your variables defined.

Can you console.log your $scope.params.workgroupId and $scope.params.reportedOn variables right before your $http.get.  I'm betting that they are undefined.  I just put the following into one of my programs (removed the .params just for convenience; unless you're thinking that's needed for some reason?) and added the $http dependency in my controller and it worked just fine.

```
$scope.workgroupId = 1;
$scope.reportedOn = 2;
$http.get("/api/v1/entries", {params: {workgroupId:$scope.workgroupId, reportedOn:$scope.reportedOn}});
```

Comment: You are correct. I did an alert($scope.params) and I get undefined. What I don't understand is before calling the alert I actually populate the $scope.params object by calling Get on the WebApi and the data shows up on my page fine. Why would $scope.params be undefined right after the $http call, but have data as the page loads? Wait a minute - I bet it's a timing thing because the $http call is asynchronous and I'm referencing $scope.params BEFORE the data is returned to it.  Ah... that makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: You got it!  Put your code above within the success callback.

Comment: Ah yes. I forgot about the Success callback. Awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell for sure from what minimal sample code you have provided, but chances are that the code where your $http call is made is not within an execution context that has access to $scope.

[This works](http://plnkr.co/edit/eqqw7OFzcPcw27wQJ1wL?p=preview) (as you can see from the alert in the plnkr, the *foo* and *bar* $scope params are mapped to query params):

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [function() {}])
.controller("MainCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.params = { foo: "foo", bar: "bar" };
  $http.get("/", { params: { foo: $scope.params.foo, bar: $scope.params.bar }}) 
    // an error (404) is expected in this simple plnkr example
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // but we can inspect what query params we sent in the config object
      // passed to the error callback
      alert("Params: foo = " + config.params.foo +
           " & bar = " + config.params.bar);
    });
}]);
```

For a better explanation, please provide more detail about your problem, including sample code of your controller (and whatever component you are using for the $http call).